# Count occurrence of integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an integer array: `int[] numbers = new int[...n]; // n being limitless.`

Where all the numbers are between 0 and 100.

Say `numbers[]` was equal to: `[52, 67, 32, 43, 32, 21, 12, 5, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0];`

I want to count how often each of those numbers occur.

I've got a second array: `int[] occurrences = new int[100];`.

I'd like to be able to store the amounts like such:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   // Store amount of 0's in numbers[] to occurrences[0] 
   // Store amount of 1's in numbers[] to occurrences[1]
}
```

So that `occurrences[0]` would be equal to 3, `occurrences[1]` would be equal to 0 etc.

Is there any efficient way of doing this without having to resort to external libraries? thanks.

Comment: This is a basic counting problem. Instead of trying to find an external library how would you try to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: You could go with a `Map<number, occurrences>`

Comment: @Prince Why?  An array is just as good for this problem.

Comment: `array.length` gives you the count of integers in an `int[]`.  :-).

Comment: @DavidWallace I suggested another approach to do it; One map instead of two arrays. Array is good as well for this purpose.

Comment: But you would have one array and one map as opposed to two arrays, or am I misunderstanding the situation? The original question already involves at least one array...

Comment: This sounds like someone is using stackoverflow to do their homework in an intro computer science class.

Comment: @icedwater Ah! Maybe I misunderstood it. I meant to have just a Map in which keys would act like numbers[] and values would act like occurrences[].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply do something like this:

```
for (int a : numbers) {
    occurrences[a]++;
}
```

Also, if you mean 0 to 100 *inclusive* then `occurrences` will need to be of size 101 (i.e. 100 will need to be the maximum index).

You might also want to perform an "assertion" to ensure that each element of `numbers` is indeed in the valid range before you update `occurrences`.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated to put results in the 100-array.*

```
import  java.util.Iterator;
import  java.util.Map;
import  java.util.Set;
import  java.util.TreeMap;

/**
   <P>{@code java IntOccurancesInArray}</P>
 **/
public class IntOccurancesInArray  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      int[] ai = new int[]{52, 67, 32, 43, 32, 21, 12, 5, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0};
      Map<Integer,Integer> mpNumWHits = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();
      for(int i = 0; i < ai.length; i++)  {
         int iValue = ai[i];
         if(!mpNumWHits.containsKey(iValue))  {
            mpNumWHits.put(iValue, 1);
         }  else  {
            mpNumWHits.put(iValue, (mpNumWHits.get(iValue) + 1));
         }
      }

      Set<Integer> stInts = mpNumWHits.keySet();
      Iterator<Integer> itrInts = stInts.iterator();

      int[] ai100 = new int[100];

      int i = 0;
      while(itrInts.hasNext())  {
         int iValue = itrInts.next();
         int iHits = mpNumWHits.get(iValue);
         System.out.println(iValue + " found " + iHits + " times");
         ai100[iValue] = iHits;
      }

      for(int j = 0; j < ai100.length; j++)  {
         if(ai100[j] > 0)  {
            System.out.println("ai100[" + j + "]=" + ai100[j]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java IntOccurancesInArray
0 found 3 times
2 found 1 times
3 found 1 times
5 found 1 times
12 found 1 times
21 found 1 times
32 found 2 times
43 found 1 times
52 found 1 times
67 found 1 times
ai100[0]=3
ai100[2]=1
ai100[3]=1
ai100[5]=1
ai100[12]=1
ai100[21]=1
ai100[32]=2
ai100[43]=1
ai100[52]=1
ai100[67]=1
```

Comment: While this may work, don't you think it's a bit complicated considering all you need to do is count numbers and the OP couldn't do that in the first place?

Comment: It's what came to me. It works. The other answer is elegant. Use it. You learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

This method is useful for knowing occurrences of all elements 
You can reduce the space by finding the length of new array using sorting and taking value of last element + 1

```
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class ArrayMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int a[] = {52, 67, 32, 43, 32, 21, 12, 5, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0};
            Arrays.sort(a);
            int len=a[a.length-1]+1;
            int count[]=new int[len];
            for(int n:a){
                count[n]++;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<count.length;j++){
                if(count[j]>=1){
                System.out.println("count:"+j+"---"+count[j]);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Time Complexity : O(n) 
Space Complexity : O(R) // last element value +1

Note : Creating new array may not be good idea if you have extreme numbers like 1, 2 and 96, 99 etc in terms of space.
For this case sorting and comparing next element is better approach

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountNumOccurences {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int[] frequency = new int[100];


      System.out.println("Enter the first integer: ");
      int number = input.nextInt();

      //Enter up to 100 integers, 0 to terminate
      while (number != 0){
         ++frequency[number];

         //read the next integer
            System.out.print(
                "Enter the next int value (zero to exit): ");
            number = input.nextInt();
      } 
      input.close();

      System.out.println("Value\tFrequency");
      for (int i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++) {
         if (frequency[i] > 0){
            if (frequency[i] > 1)  
               System.out.println(i + " occurs " + frequency[i] + " times");
            else
               System.out.println(i + " occurs " + frequency[i] + " time");
         }
      }
   }
}
```